# I Need A Good Book On Elementary Algebra and analysis.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to study a course with course code MTH230 (Elementary algebra and analysis).

The course outline are:

1. Set theory
2. Cartesian product
3. Mappings
4. Peano's axiom
5. Construction of integers & rational numbers
6. Dedekind cut
7. Cardinal number
8. Bounds of real number
9. Division algorithm
10. Primes
11. Fundamental theorem of arithmetic G.C.D & E.C.M

Is there any book I can buy that deals with these topics that is full of examples and explanations?

Comment: Perhaps you can advise us what textbook is currently being used for that course?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any single book has all these topics. According to me best way for you is to google each name followed by pdf. For Example google "Peano's Axioms pdf"" and you will see various notes from universities across the globe and choose which approach suits you well.

Comment: I have done this but none of them have problem and solution just theorem upon theorems.